# WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading not called in API 19

Tags: android, webview

I need to catch malformed links `(without "http://")` in a webpage loaded by the app (through a `WebView` container) and format them correctly `(adding "http://")` which I do by Overriding

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url).

    if(url.startsWith("/")){
        url = "http://www.domain.com" + url;
    }
```

Everything was nice but I realize that in API 19 it fails to call `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method according [to this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html).
But they do not say which method gets to be call to decide if it is a valid or not valid url.

Solutions like get all web content from the page to load, find and replace the bad formatted links and then load that "new" page instead seems to much effort for something so little.

Does anyone knows what method to override (intercepting clicks from the WebView)?

Answer (score -1):

Google has some [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#URLs) regarding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` in KitKat:

> The new WebView applies additional restrictions when requesting resources and resolving links that use a custom URL scheme. For
>   example, if you implement callbacks such as shouldOverrideUrlLoading()
>   or shouldInterceptRequest(), then WebView invokes them only for valid
>   URLs.
>
> If you are using a custom URL scheme or a base URL and notice that your app is receiving fewer calls to these callbacks or failing to
>   load resources on Android 4.4, ensure that the requests specify valid
>   URLs that conform to RFC 3986.

Comment: Thanks @Wei but the link you refer is the one I stated in my question. That was the reason of my question. I do not control the webpage to view and so I do not control directly the way the links are formatted. Meaning I need to get the click in the not well formatted links so I can format them correctly. I was catching with shouldOverrideUrlLoading() but in the Android 4.4 I can not do it. I need another way to do it.